# React JS App with Google Authentication. Hide Google Login button button on authentication

Tags: reactjs, google-authenticator

I am new to React, and want to use Google Authentication. I am hiding my UI until the users is authenticated. Up to now the App is working as expected. My issue is when the user authenticates and the UI shows the Google Login button still shows. I would like it not to show, if the user does a hard refresh the button will go away.

Current code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // Check if the user is already authenticated from storage
    window.onload = () => {
      const storedUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
      if (storedUser) {
        setUser(storedUser);
      } else {
        // Initialize Google Sign-In only if not already authenticated
        const signInOptions = {
          client_id: '',
        };

        google.accounts.id.initialize({
          client_id: signInOptions.client_id,
          callback: handleSignIn,
        });

        // Render the Google Sign-In button
        google.accounts.id.renderButton(document.getElementById('g_id_onload'), {
          theme: 'filled_blue',
          size: 'large',
          shape: 'pill',
          text: 'signin_with',
          logo_alignment: 'left',
          ux_mode: 'popup',
          context: 'signin',
        });
      }
      
      }
      // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
 }, []);

  return (
    <div className="app">
      {user ? (
        // Show UI only if the user is authenticated
        <>
          <div className="header">
            <div className="logo-container">
              {/* Add your logo image here */}
              <img src="/logo.png" alt="Logo" className="logo" />
            </div>
            <div className="title">Special Consideration Attempt Lookup</div>
          </div>
          <div className="input-container">
            <div className="input-box">
              <label htmlFor="studentId">Student ID</label>
              <input type="text" id="studentId" value={studentId} onChange={handleStudentIdChange} />
              <span className="required-asterisk">*</span>
            </div>

            <div className="input-box">
              <label htmlFor="unitCode">Unit Code</label>
              <input type="text" id="unitCode" value={unitCode} onChange={handleUnitCodeChange} />
            </div>

            <div className="input-box">
              <label htmlFor="examYear">Exam Year</label>
              <input
                type="number"
                id="examYear"
                value={examYear}
                onChange={handleExamYearChange}
              />
              <span className="required-asterisk">*</span>
            </div>

            <button className="search-button" onClick={handleSearchClick}>
              Search
            </button>

            <button className="clear-button" onClick={handleClearClick}>
              Clear
            </button>
          </div>
          {loading && (
            <div className="loading-spinner-overlay">
              <div className="loading-spinner"></div>
            </div>
          )}
          <div
            className="ag-theme-alpine"
            style={{
              height: '400px',
              width: '100%',
              marginTop: '20px',
            }}
          >
            <AgGridReact
              columnDefs={columnDefs}
              rowData={rowData}
              onGridReady={(params) => {
                gridRef.current = params.api;
              }}
            />
          </div>
        </>
        ) : null}
    <div
      id="g_id_onload"
      data-client_id=""
      data-context="signin"
      data-ux_mode="popup"
    >
      <div
        className="g_id_signin"
        data-type="standard"
        data-shape="pill"
        data-theme="filled_blue"
        data-text="signin_with"
        data-size="large"
        data-logo_alignment="left"
      ></div>
    </div>
  </div>
);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to change ternary.

In JSX, the ternary pattern works as follows

```
<div>
{  condition ? (
      stuff if true
   ) : (
      struff if false
   )
}
</div>
```

Here is a super-simple stripped down mock of a login ternary:

```js
function App(props) {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState(false)
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      {user ? (
        <div onClick={() => setUser(false)}>
           You are now logged in (click to log out)
        </div>
      ) : (
        <input type="button" onClick={() => setUser(true)} value="Login" />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App title="I'm the thingy" />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

In your particular case replacing  `) : null}` and below with the following should solve the problem:

```js
  ) : (
    <div
      id="g_id_onload"
      data-client_id=""
      data-context="signin"
      data-ux_mode="popup"
    >
      <div
        className="g_id_signin"
        data-type="standard"
        data-shape="pill"
        data-theme="filled_blue"
        data-text="signin_with"
        data-size="large"
        data-logo_alignment="left"
      ></div>
    </div> )}
  </div>
);
}
```

Alternatively you could wrap the Login stuff in it's own ternary as well.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and unfortunately, it did not work. Also I am new to react and unsure of the terminology 'Ternary'

Comment: What result are you getting? Is it still showing, or are you getting an error?

Comment: `{  condition ? (<>stuff if true</>) : (<>struff if false</>) }` is the general ternary pattern

Comment: No not getting error, Basically I am using the google authentication library "https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client". The library includes a Authentic Google Sign in button. So when my site first loads it goes to a white page with the Signin button in the middle of the page (This is correct). The user Authenticates through Google once AUthenticated the UI loads (Which is correct) But the Google login button shifts to the header space of the page. Only way to get rid of it is to Refresh the page.

Comment: Where are you actually setting the user state? That might be where the issue is.

Comment: I finally worked it out. Was missing defer when calling the library <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>

Comment: Good news! Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

Hide the Login button when the user isn't authenticated by using this format

```
user ? ( 

  UI
) : (
  Login button
)
```

```
return (
  <div className="app">
      {user ? (
        // Show UI only if the user is authenticated
        <>
          <div className="header">
            <div className="logo-container">
              {/* Add your logo image here */}
              <img src="/logo.png" alt="Logo" className="logo" />
            </div>
            <div className="title">Special Consideration Attempt Lookup</div>
          </div>
          <div className="input-container">
            <div className="input-box">
              <label htmlFor="studentId">Student ID</label>
              <input type="text" id="studentId" value={studentId} onChange={handleStudentIdChange} />
              <span className="required-asterisk">*</span>
            </div>

            <div className="input-box">
              <label htmlFor="unitCode">Unit Code</label>
              <input type="text" id="unitCode" value={unitCode} onChange={handleUnitCodeChange} />
            </div>

            <div className="input-box">
              <label htmlFor="examYear">Exam Year</label>
              <input
                type="number"
                id="examYear"
                value={examYear}
                onChange={handleExamYearChange}
              />
              <span className="required-asterisk">*</span>
            </div>

            <button className="search-button" onClick={handleSearchClick}>
              Search
            </button>

            <button className="clear-button" onClick={handleClearClick}>
              Clear
            </button>
          </div>
          {loading && (
            <div className="loading-spinner-overlay">
              <div className="loading-spinner"></div>
            </div>
          )}
          <div
            className="ag-theme-alpine"
            style={{
              height: '400px',
              width: '100%',
              marginTop: '20px',
            }}
          >
            <AgGridReact
              columnDefs={columnDefs}
              rowData={rowData}
              onGridReady={(params) => {
                gridRef.current = params.api;
              }}
            />
          </div>
        </>
        ) : (
 

        <div
          id="g_id_onload"
          data-client_id=""
          data-context="signin"
          data-ux_mode="popup"
        >
          <div
            className="g_id_signin"
            data-type="standard"
            data-shape="pill"
            data-theme="filled_blue"
            data-text="signin_with"
            data-size="large"
            data-logo_alignment="left"
          ></div>
       </div>

)}
   
  </div>

);
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I have tried this and still no luck. Basically, I load the site a white page with the google sign in button shows correct so far. The user signs in, then the UI shows correct. BUT the Google sign in button is still visible on the page but shifts to the top right in my header space of the page. Only fix is to Manually refresh the page then it works. If I use this as a very temporary measure it works: window.location.reload();

Any other suggestions would be appreciated. If you need more of the code let me no. Cheers

Comment: I have modified my answer. The UI loads when the state `user` is mutated `setUser(storedUser);` I have used ternary to toggle the result of if `user` is loaded or not.